# What is the best way or best practice to keep multiple databases synced for java enterprise projects?

Tags: java, database, synchronization

in every project I have multiples environments such us Dev, Sit, Uat and Prod. In each of them I have a database.

It is bothering to execute the sql scripts in Dev and then repeat this step against every environment.

Is there a good way, a good tool or a best practice to keep databases synced against all these environments?

Heard about some tools like LiquiBase and Flyway but don't have experience about them. Is its use a good practice?

Comment: Normally you put such sequence of SQL queries into a file, then you execute the contents of a file. Is this a problem? Some frameworks have built-in support for database migrations.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo thanks for the comment. I'll update the question to be more specific. I'm investigating about this and found a very interesting tool for Java named Flyway, it handles sql migrations quite easily similar to migrations in Ruby On Rails. There are also a tool more complex named LiquiBase that is a kind of abstraction to handle databases. I've never used both of them but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question about best way or best practices to do it. Thanks indeed by your comment.

Comment: Yup, migration tools are useful. From the examples given, I would pick Flyway because LiquiBase is more advanced and probably you're not gonna need most of it's features.